# Java program divisible by three without using modulus

Tags: java

I'd like to create a program wherein a user will type a number and the program will tell if it is divisible by 3 or not. But %, /, +, * can't be used in the program. Anybody here got some ideas how to do that?

Comment: Homework? Or why can't you use `%`?

Comment: Homework? Than tag it as such? Not homework? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: No, it's not a homework, I'd like to do it without those operators.

Comment: So you only want to use the `-` operator ?

Comment: Looks like you'll have to go through a loop of subtraction while making sure the remainder isn't 0 or less than 3.

Comment: homework tag is apparently deprecated

Comment: @Matteo actually, I'd like to have an idea how to solve the java game I had just seen.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - I think we can safely ignore that ... even if it is true.  And I don't think it is true, judging from the tag's wiki.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String number = "123456";

    int sum = 0;
    for (char c : number.toCharArray()) {
        sum = sum - (0 - c) - '0';
        while (sum >= 3) {
            sum -= 3;
        }
    }
    System.out.print("divisible by 3? ");
    System.out.println(sum == 0);
}
```

Alternatively you can keep subtracting 3 until your number is either 0 (divisible by 3) or <0: not divisible by 3.

ps: it needs to be adapted if you want to deal with negative numbers

Comment: This works because a number is divisible by 3 if and only if the sum of its digits in base 10 are also divisible by 3.

Comment: @Mysticial Yes that's the idea.

Comment: Perhaps change `sum > 3` to `sum >= 3` and remove `sum == 3` at the bottom?

Comment: how about: `if (num / 3 == num / 3.0) { ... }` where `num = Integer.parseInt(number);`

Answer (score 3):

easy peasy...

```
boolean divisibleBy3(int n) {
    return (""+n).matches("([0369]|[147]([0369]|[147][0369]*[258])*([" +
                          "258]|[147][0369]*[147])|[258]([0369]|[258]" +
                          "[0369]*[147])*([147]|[258][0369]*[258]))*");
}
```

Comment: +1 - That's the ugliest regex ever!! And it works (no idea how by the way!)

Comment: You are using `+` to concatenate strings. Since it is not allowed you should use one single string for the regular expression and `Integer.toString(n)` for the string conversion.

Answer (score 2):

A number is divisible by there if the sum of all the digits is also divisible by 3. You can iterate the process until you have a number smaller than 10 and compare it which known divisors (3,6 and 9)

Since it is most likely a game or homework and you can use `+` you can simple use minus two times: `a - - b` is equivalent to `a + b`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use the - operator then

```
bool divBy3(int n)
{
  while (n >= 0)
  {
    n -= 3;
  }

  return n == 0;
}
```

This will return true if n is exactly divisible by 3, false otherwise. Note that this is really inefficient! Using the % operator would be far better.

Comment: Hi, how can I display true if it is divisible by 3? THanks

Comment: int x = 17;
System.out.println(divBy3(x));

Comment: Hello i tried this   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     
  int m;
    
  System.out.println( "Enter a number: " );
  m = in.nextInt();
    
    
  System.out.print(divby3(m));

Answer (score 0):

Divisibility by 3 in binary representation is like divisibility by 11 in decimal (10+1): sum of digits in even places minus sum of digits on odd places is in turn divisible by 3 (maybe 0).